# i can't see more my global object created by Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/myfile.jsm") in firefox 17

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, global-variables

I have used next code to create MyGlobalObject in my MultiWindows application in firefox 15- .

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/MyGlobalObject.jsm");
```

My file MyGlobalObject.jsm is very simple:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [ "MyGlobalObject" ];
if ("undefined" == typeof(MyGlobalObject)) {
    var MyGlobalObject = {};
    MyGlobalObject[0]=1;
}
```

Since firefox 17+ this code doesn't operate.
I have created add-on with next main.js:

```
exports.main = function() {
   var { Cu } = require("chrome");
   Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/MyGlobalObject.jsm");
};
```

Nevertheless I can't access MyGlobalObject in my Javascript-code inside of my application.
In what my misunderstanding programming for firefox 17+ consists?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating add-ons with the Add-on SDK, `Cu.import()` won't recognize the scope of your package correctly. This means that you have to [assign the exported symbols explicitly](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/02/16/using-jsm-modules-in-the-sdk/):

```js
var {Cu} = require("chrome");
var {MyGlobalObject} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/MyGlobalObject.jsm", null);
```

Comment: Wladimir, thank You for Your answer. I create my addon through Add-on Builder. So this code is the subject of exports.main = function() . But I have the same result in javascript-code on the page: alert(typeof($$$gtZXPComObject)) gets "undefined". I can't understand this situation.